# Unable to use the OPENSSL method with android studio NDK project. undefined reference to 'EVP_add_cipher'

Tags: android, openssl, android-ndk

I have been tried to working with android project linking with openssl1.1.1d. But Still I am getting issue.

COnfiguration:-

1. ANDROID ARCH = android64
2. ANDROID STUDIO = 3.5 TO 3.6.1
3. OS = ubuntu 18.04
4. NDK = 21.0.6113669
5. abi = arm64-v8a

**any type of more details, please let me know.**

I have started learning openssl from [here](https://proandroiddev.com/tutorial-compile-openssl-to-1-1-1-for-android-application-87137968fee). I have beed followed all the steps and successfully generated the libssl.so, libssl.a, libcrypto.so and libcrypto.a

I have uploaded my code into [github public repo](https://github.com/PeterDasondhi/opensslAndroidLinking). Please check and help me to solve the issue.

In advance thank you so much and it will appricateable.
Please pull the code and let me know where I am going wrong. [clone the sample code](https://github.com/PeterDasondhi/opensslAndroidLinking.git)

Answer (score 0):

After making the natural adaptations (e.g. replace hardcoded paths, add `abiFilters "arm64_v8a"`, fix the `hello-jni.c` file, choose **arm8Debug** as *Active Build Varian*t) – everything seems to compile cleanly.

Please see https://github.com/PeterDasondhi/opensslAndroidLinking/pull/1.

The actual problem with your build probably was that you were building for armv7, but provided the libraries for armv8.